# Segfault in the middle of a function when I run a posterior function

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, global-variables

My exercise is to write a parser of a string to the written form of a number in English, I can get the number with no problem, and write it back parsed in the format we chose to store. But if after the printing I call another function I get segfault in the middle of the printing.
this

```
int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *digits; 
    char *dictionary;

    read_input(&digits, &dictionary, argc, argv);
    check_stored_numbers();
}
```

prints this

```
c2r6p4% ./a.out 24234

exp 0  units 234
exp 1  units 24%
```

this

```
int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *digits; 
    char *dictionary;

    read_input(&digits, &dictionary, argc, argv);
    check_stored_numbers();
    load_dict(dictionary);
}
```

prints this:

```
c2r6p4% ./a.out 24234 
exp 0  units 234 
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out 24234
```

Specifically, the parsed number goes to a global variable array, which is marked from a global pointer. I tried to hide many specific parts in a step fashion but in the end, it boils down to this issue. I will try to place the code in the next session, I know there is a lot of bad code, contrived solutions, and general stuff to be improved. But I need specifically an insight as to why a future function call is able to segfault a previously running program.
I am running Ubuntu, compiling with cc * -Wall -Werror -Wextra at this point.

```
#include "functions.h"

int char_to_digit(char c)
{
    return (c - '0');
}



#include "functions.h"

void check_only_digits(char *digits)
{
    while (*digits != '\0')
    {
        if ((*digits >= '0') && (*digits <= '9'))
        {
            digits++;
        }
        else
        {
            ft_putstr("error");
            exit (1) ;
        }
    }
    return ;
}

#include "functions.h"

void free_mem(void *pointer)
{
    if (pointer != NULL)
        {
            free(pointer);
        }
}

#include "functions.h"

void    ft_openfile()
{
    char *conteudo = NULL;
    int arquivo;
    ssize_t tamanho;
    
    arquivo = open ("numbers.dict", O_RDONLY);
    if (arquivo == -1)
    {
        perror("Erro ao abrir arquivo");
        exit (1) ;
    }
    tamanho = lseek(arquivo, 0 , SEEK_END);
    conteudo = (char *)malloc(tamanho + 1);
    if (conteudo == NULL)
    {
        perror("Erro ao alocar memoria");
        close(arquivo);
        exit(1);
    }
    lseek(arquivo, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ssize_t bytes = read(arquivo, conteudo, tamanho);
    if (bytes == -1)
    {
        perror("Erro ao alocar memoria");
        free(conteudo);
        close(arquivo);
        exit (1) ;
    }
    conteudo[tamanho] = '\0';
    printf("arquivo:\n%s", conteudo);
    free(conteudo);
    close(arquivo);
}

#include "functions.h"

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    long    number;
    
    number = (long)nb;
    if (number < 0)
    {   ft_putchar('-');
        number = number * -1;
    }

    if (number < 10)
    {
        ft_putchar(number + '0');
    }

    if (number >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr(number / 10);
        ft_putnbr(number % 10);
    }
}

#include "functions.h"

void    ft_putstr(char (*str))
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != 0)
    {
        write(1, &str[i], 1);
        i++;
    }
}

#include "functions.h"

char    *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{   
    int count;

    count = 0;
    while (src[count] != '\0')
    {       
        dest[count] = src[count];
        count++;
    }
    dest[count] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}


#include "functions.h"

int ft_strlen(char (*str))
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (i);
}

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "types.h"


void    ft_putstr(char (*str));
void    ft_putchar(char c);
int     ft_strlen(char (*str));
void    ft_putnbr(int nb);
char    *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src);
void    check_only_digits(char *digits);
void    read_input_dict(char **dictionary, char *argv);
void    read_input_digits(char **digits, char *argv);
void    read_input(char **digits, char **dictionary, int argc, char **argv);
void    free_mem(void *pointer);
int     parse_blocks(char *digits);
void    str_end(char **str);
int     char_to_digit(char c);
void    store_user_numbers(char *digits);
int     parse_number(char **read_digits, char *digits);
void    load_dict(char *dict);

#endif



#include "types.h"

dict_num    *g_dict;
parsed_num *g_user_numbers;
int g_blocks = 1;

#include "types.h"

#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

extern dict_num    *g_dict;
extern parsed_num *g_user_numbers;
extern int g_blocks;

#endif



#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"

void    load_dict(char *dict)
{
    ft_strlen(dict);
    g_dict = malloc(sizeof(dict_num) * 41);

    g_dict[0].number.exponent = 0;
    g_dict[0].number.units = 0;
    g_dict[0].name = "zero";

    // a large number of lines

    g_dict[40].number.exponent = 36;
    g_dict[40].number.units = 1;
    g_dict[40].name = "undecillion";
}



#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"

void    check_stored_numbers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < g_blocks; i++)
    {
        printf("\nexp %i  units %i", g_user_numbers[i].exponent, g_user_numbers[i].units);
    }
}

void    check_stored_dict()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 41; i++)
    {
        printf("exp %i  units %i  name %s\n", g_dict[i].number.exponent, g_dict[i].number.units, g_dict[i].name );
    }
}

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *digits; 
    char *dictionary;

    read_input(&digits, &dictionary, argc, argv);
    check_stored_numbers();
    //load_dict(dictionary);
    
    //check_stored_dict();
    //free(dictionary);
    //free(digits);
    //free(g_user_numbers);
}




#include "functions.h"

int parse_blocks(char *digits)
{
    int number_of_digits;
    int number_of_blocks;

    number_of_digits = ft_strlen(digits);
    number_of_blocks = number_of_digits / 3;
    if ((number_of_digits % 3) != 0)
        number_of_blocks++;
    return (number_of_blocks);
}



#include "functions.h"

int power(int base, int exp)
{
    if (exp == 0)
        return (1);
    if (exp == 1)
        return (base);
    return (base * power(base, exp - 1));
}

int parse_number(char **read_digits, char *digits)
{
    int return_value;
    int count;

    count = 3;
    return_value = 0;
    while ((*read_digits != digits - 1) && (count >= 1))
    {
        return_value = return_value +(power(10, 3 - count) * (char_to_digit(**read_digits)));
        (*read_digits)--;
        count--;
    }
    return (return_value);
}



#include "functions.h"

void read_input(char **digits, char **dictionary, int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        ft_putstr("error");
        exit (1) ;
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        read_input_digits(digits, argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        read_input_dict(dictionary, argv[1]);
        read_input_digits(digits, argv[2]);
    }
}



#include "functions.h"

void read_input_dict(char **dictionary, char *argv)
{
    *dictionary = malloc ((ft_strlen(argv)+1) * sizeof(char));
    *dictionary = ft_strcpy(*dictionary, argv);
    //ft_putstr(*dictionary);
}



#include "functions.h"

void read_input_digits(char **digits, char *argv)
    {
        *digits = malloc((ft_strlen(argv)+1) * sizeof(char));
        *digits = ft_strcpy(*digits, argv);
        check_only_digits(*digits);
        store_user_numbers(*digits);
        //ft_putstr(*digits);
        //ft_putchar('\n');
    }
    


#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"

void store_user_numbers(char *digits)
{
    int count_blocks, count_digits, user_number;
    char *read_digits;

    read_digits = digits;
    count_digits = 0;
    count_blocks = 0;
    g_blocks = parse_blocks(digits);
    g_user_numbers = malloc(sizeof(parsed_num) * g_blocks);
    str_end(&read_digits);
    while (count_blocks < g_blocks)
    {
        g_user_numbers[count_blocks].exponent = count_blocks;
        g_user_numbers[count_blocks].units = parse_number(&read_digits, digits);
        count_blocks++;
    }
}



#include "functions.h"

void str_end(char **str)
{
    while(**str != '\0')
    {
        (*str)++;
    }
    (*str)--;
}



#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

typedef struct{
    int exponent;
    int units;
}parsed_num;

typedef struct{
    parsed_num number;
    char *name;
}dict_num;

#endif
```

Comment: Side note: do `#include "functions.h"` only once at the top

Comment: To debug: recompile with `-g`. Run via `gdb  ./a.out` then `set args  24234` and `run` when it faults, type `bt` to see where it happened

Comment: Craig, thank you a lot for your input. To be clear, that "dump" is from the entire project, each #include "functions.h" pertains to a file, it is basically one function from file, few exeptions. And the includes in "functions.h" are in safeguards, so I would assume there would be no double inclusion. I will tru to learn a little about the debugger, never used one. But still, the question, from an abstract conceptual level is in no way clear to me. How can a function in "the future" produce a segfault in the current function?

Comment: Create a _single_ `.c` that has everything (and _no_ `#include "functions.h"`). It should compile cleanly. Edit your question and post this in a code block at the bottom. Is the code block at the bottom already that except for the `#include` issue? If we downloaded the block and built and ran it as I've described, would it fault as you've described?

Comment: Another way to debug is to compile with `-fsanitize=address` and rerun normally. This may help find the exact point where the program goes wrong

Comment: Forgive me for saying so, but this is a ridiculous spread of functions into individual files... Look at `char_to_digit()`... No reader wants to go off to hunt down another function that performs such a basic operation. Standard library headers are included (indirectly) in every source file. Why are you writing your own versions? `free_mem()`, for example, is not called from anywhere in this code. `ft_openfile()` does a lot more than simply opening a file...

Comment: I've downloaded [and cleaned up] your final code block. I've run it under `gdb` and it exits normally. Is this the version that should fault? `ft_openfile` does a `free` of the buffer that is created. So, it reads in the data from a file, but _discards_ that data. This would cause segfaults, etc. but the code does _not_ call it anywhere.

Comment: The problem is a toy problem, there are clearly very contrived workarounds that have to do with demands of the course I am at, Fe2O3. All in all anyone is excused for pointing these weird issues out, I see value in your comment, there are many places where some more care is due. The exercise is going to be corrected based on functions having less than a number of parameters and a number of lines, and this is in the origin of many of the functions you saw, also we can´t use but a few specific library functions and rewrite the rest.

Comment: Thanks again, Craig, I appriciate your guidance. I know that if all is in a single file I will have no issues with the global variables, my goal is to get them to work across files. Still, what I really am unable to grasp is how something can cause a segfault before it is used in the program. This is what is actually bugging me. Is there some particular information I should have about cross file compilation that might answer this? It is defying logic, we can´t have consequences before the facts.

Comment: "_is a toy problem_" It certainly is! Using roll-y'r-own replacements for standard library functions is just plain dumb (and shouldn't be taught, imo). Prescribed restrictions on parameter count or # of lines is also dumb. Priority #1 should be clean and correct code. If a function can be cleanly written in 31-32 lines, a limit of 30 lines means the code will have to be less clear. PS: In English, `42` => "Forty Two". In German, `42` ==> "Zwei (two) UND Vierzig (forty)"... Difficult making ONE algorithm truly international (using an external lexicon)...(India's number system departs further!)

Comment: Fe2O3, or should I just call you Iron Man (no Ironyee, please take no ofense), the school is actually pretty good, and I am learning a lot. But I agree a lot with your criticism, although the constrains do help us build a "shortening the problem" muscle, it does get unreasonably arbitrary from time to time. It turns out I just dropped the idea of global variables and bypassed the issue of number of parameters per function in another way, so the problem is kind of stale.

Comment: Still, any insight as to why "the future is corrupting the present" so to speak, in so far as my functions logic, and what specific errors of my code might be implicated on that, would surely be very important for me. I actually feel like I'll never be able to use global variables again and steel keep my anxiety at bay.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` and the rest of the standard i/o functions are *buffered*, meaning that when you call them they don't actually print everything immediately. Since i/o operations are so slow, they accumulate stuff into an internal buffer and only print when they have enough data (or when you explicitly tell them to).
I don't know if this is exactly your problem (you call Linux-specific functions and I'm on Windows), but you can try two things:

- Convert `printf(...)` into `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, since stderr is not buffered.
- Call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` (this is how you explicitly tell it to print immediately)

If my assumption is correct, either of these two things should make the program appear to crash where it actually crashes, so in `ft_strlen`.

P.S. I don't think that writing your own versions of standard functions is dumb, unless you're in a hurry. It's a great exercise, even if they your functions turned out worse. The main reason I remembered this buffering thing is that last time I wrote my own printing function that printed every single character individually, I *experienced the incredible slowness* of it - printing a simple message was slower than a whole software rendering routine! Rewrite things often, my friend. Not necessarily to reinvent the wheel, but to understand why a square wouldn't work.

Comment: this answer is really amazing, and also helped me understand the kind of issue I fell into. Thaks a lot, really helpfull!